# is it possible to access a controller in a managed package from a customer org?

Tags: managed-package

I've tried several different ways to be able to access a controller in a managed package from a visualforce page created inside the customer org.

- I could not reference the package controller directly  `controller="packageCtrl"`
- I could not reference it with the namespace `controller="nmspc__packageCtrl"`
- I also tried declaring packageCtrl to be a `virtual` class, creating a controller in the customer org that extends it and that doesn't seem to work either, even if its declared to be `global virtual`

Any other ideas? Has anyone accomplished this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

classes and methods needs to be global to access controller from managed package

Please go through this [link](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/05/salesforce-referencing-installed.html)

Comment: The managed class is global yet when I try to reference it from a local class via extends like : public with sharing class mycontroller extends packageCtrl I'm getting an invalid type compiler error

Comment: please check for version settings of your class and managed class

Comment: I think I figured it out. The namespace for the package is still required and you have to reference them like 'namespace.classname'